# Mean Value Theorem for semi-differentiable multivariate functions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, mean-value-theorem

The paper "*Wituła, R.; Hetmaniok, E.; Słota, D.*, Mean-value theorem for one-sided differentiable functions, Fasc. Math. 48, 143-154 (2012). [ZBL1259.26003](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1259.26003)." discusses some generalizations of the Mean Value Theorem (MVT) when one considers the setting where a function has one-sided derivatives but may not be differentiable.

They state the following Theorem:

> If $f:[a, b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is both-sided differentiable in
> $(a,b)$, right-continuous at $a$, left-continuous at $b$, then there
> exists $c \in (a, b), p, q \geq 0, p + q = 1$ such that $\frac{f(b) -
> > f(a)}{b-a} = p f'(c+) + qf'(c-)$ where $f'(c+)$ denotes the right
> derivative and $f'(c-)$ the left derivative.

And then remark that based on this Theorem the following inequality holds:

> There exists $c \in (a, b)$ sucht hat
>
> $\min \{ f'(c-), f'(c+) \} \leq \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} \leq \max \{ f'(c-), f'(c+) \}$

I am now wondering whether something similar can be stated in the multivariate case where  $f: S \subset \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ only has one-sided partial derivatives.

The [MVT in multivariate case](http://www.math.toronto.edu/courses/mat237y1/20199/notes/Chapter2/S2.4.html) for differentiable $f: S \subset \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is stated as:

> For two points $a, b \in S$, let $L_{a, b}$ denote the line segment
> that connects them. If $L_{a,b} \subseteq S$ there exists $c \in L_{a,b}$ such that
>
> $$f(b)-f(a) = (b-a)^T \nabla f(c)$$

If we now suppose that $f$ is not differentiable but only has one-sided partial derivatives, is there an inequality similar to the case where $f$ is univariate?

Comment: Check Dieudonne's _Foundations of Modern Analysis_ chapter 8 where he deals with the MVT. Cartan's _Differentiable Calculus_ deals with MVT when only right-derivatives exist. Both books are for normed vector spaces (the assumption of completeness is not used in differential calculus unless integrals are also considered).

Comment: @WilliamM. thank you for your suggestions! As far as I have read Dieudonne's Foundations of Modern Analysis only deals with the case where f is differentiable and Cartan's Diferential Calculus only deals with this case when the function is univariate, or am I missing something?

Comment: They both deal with functions with values in Banach spaces, however, completeness is rarely used (it is definitely used when integrals are involved but not otherwise).

Comment: @WilliamM. I have not found a similar MVT inequality for the multivariate case where the function only has left & right derivatives in either of these sources. Are you referring to a specific page where you have seen it?

Comment: In Cartan's book, p. 38, theorem 3.1.2 is a MVT for right derivatives only. Dieudonne's (8.5.1) extends to right derivatives, the proof is identical as that given by Dieudonne's. The general idea for a vector function (i.e. argument is vector) is to consider the real function (i.e. argument is real) where the we parametrise the line between two vectors $a$ and $b$ as $(1-t)a + tb.$

Comment: @WilliamM. Cartan's Theorem 3.1.2 and Dieudonne's 8.5.1 both consider unviariate functions since the functions map from a closed interval to a Banach space.

Comment: How do you think the multivariate MVT is proved usually? Usually by considering two points $a$ and $b$ in your normed space, and then by parametrising $t \mapsto (1-t)a + tb$ for $t \in [0,1].$