Mean Value Theorem but with corner still holds?
As beautifully shown in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem, if we have an everywhere differentiable function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and a secant between say $(a,f(a))$ and $(b,f(b))$, there is a $\xi\in[a,b]$, where the tangent at $f(\xi)$ is parallel to given secant.
Now, what if $f$ is not everywhere differentiable, but still continous, that is $f$ has a non-differentiable corner at say $s\in[a,b]$, does the Mean Value Theorem still hold, in case we allow every "tangent line" at $f(s)$ to be a candidate to being parallel to the secant?
Intuitively I would say yes, however I am struggling to prove it (or find a counterexample).

$f(x)=1-|x|$ for $x\in [-1,1]$

Rolle's Theorem does not hold with these hp, and you use it to prove the MVT

The first theorem in https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4738910/42969 might be what you are looking for.

What do you mean by "tangent line" when when $f$ is not differentiable?

I mean support lines with respect to which $f$ lies on one side. For instance consider $tf_+'(x)+(1-t)f_-'(x)$ for $t\in[0,1]$ where the corner of $f$ is at $x$. E.g. in $f(x)=1-|x|$ we allow any line $(0,1)+\mathbb{R}(1,y)$ for $y\in[-1,1]$. I hope it helps understanding my question better.
